# Cakephp 3 save associations dose not work

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, web-deployment

I try to make a blog with articles and tags but for some reason my tags wont save when creating articles.
I did followed some ideas from official cake blog and from here but no luck for me .. Maybe something I do wrong and I dont see.

Tables for keywords

```
CREATE TABLE `keywords` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table model
Keywords:

```
class KeywordsTable extends Table
{
......................
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('keywords');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Article', [
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
....................
}
```

Article

```
class ArticleTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('article');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('Keywords', [
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id'
        ]);
    }
......................................
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
public function add()
{

        //$this->autoRender = false;
        $article = $this->Article->newEntity();


        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $article = $this->Article->patchEntity($article, $this->request->data, ['associated'=>['Keywords']]);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->Article->save($article));
        die();
        }
}
```

And this is the code I use in my form

```
<?= $this->Form->input('article[keywords][]', ['label'=>false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'keywords', 'templates' => ['inputContainer' => '{{content}}']]); ?>
```

So if any one could help me out I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after 4 hours I managed to find the problem.
Problem was in my view form input.

It should have been **article.0.tag** instead of **article[keywords][]**
Changed that and all works now.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

in controller you should use associated array, [more details](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations)-

```
$this->Article->save($article,['associated' => ['Keywords']]);
```

and in view file, make input field like this -

```
<?= $this->Form->input('keywords.0.title', ['label'=>false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'keywords', 'templates' => ['inputContainer' => '{{content}}']]); ?>
```

[more details](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs)